# Как ведет себя range в for? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
item = 5

for i in range(item):
    item -= 1
    print(i, range(item), item)
```

Что-то я запутался, как так получается, что когда range(0, 1) i = 3 и вообще, что тут происходит и как это работает? Почему i доходит до конца, хотя item уменьшается, разве он не должен быть закончится раньше.

Объясните пожалуйста поподробнее, заранее спасибо за ответ на мой глупый вопрос.

Comment: Прикладывайте, пожалуйста, код не скриншотом, а кодом. Кнопка `править`

Comment: Во второй версии будет немного другой результат, потому что там ``range()`` работает не так.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`range` вызывается только один раз. Эта функция **возвращает** итерируемый объект `range`.
`for i in range(item):` в данном случае эквивалентно `for i in [0,1,2,3,4]:`, т.е. `range` не вызывается для каждой итерации, только единожды и далее цикл пробегает по элементам этой коллекции.

Answer (score 1):

В 2.x.x range возвращает list. В 3.x.x все куда лучше - там у range поведение аналогичное xrange в 2.x.x, а сама xrange вовсе убрана. xrange - в каком-то смысле прародитель генераторов, он не хранит весь список в памяти, а каждый раз вычисляет текущий элемент.